# generate GraphQL schema dynamically

Tags: graphql, owl, neo4j-apoc

Is it possible to dynamically create a GraphQL schema from an OWL/RDF ontology ??
We store the data ( here it's the ontology) in neo4j database .

Is there any way we can generate the graphql schema dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using postgres you could use [hasura](https://hasura.io/) (my favorite.) for generating instant graphql schema from your database. They built version 2.0 for handling mssql server also.

But if you insist to use neo4j you can use loopback 4 for getting graphql schema from your db. Basically they build REAST APIs. They have a [community connector for neo4j](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Community-connectors.html).

Comment: Is it possible to run the production Hasura mssql server with no internet if I am running it in local system and not in cloud?

Comment: yes, you can .. you will just give the database URL for hasura.